# Play: How to reference a HTML template in another module

Tags: scala, playframework

Given the following project structure of a `Play` app...

```
app
  └ controllers
  └ models
  └ views
conf
  └ application.conf
  └ routes
modules
  └ module1
    └ conf/module1.routes
    └ app/controllers
    └ app/models
    └ app/views
      └ a.scala.html
  └ module2
    └ conf/module2.routes
    └ app/controllers
    └ app/models
    └ app/views
      └ a.scala.html
project
 └ build.properties
 └ Build.scala
 └ plugins.sbt
```

How do I reference `a.scala.html` in `modules/module1/app/views` from `b.scala.html` in `modules/module2/app/views`?

I've tried any possible combination... but no way. As far as I know, the scope of a HTML template is given by the directory path.

Comment: If they aren't dependent on each other, you can't.. That's the point of separating things into modules, isn't it? What does your build file look like?

Comment: I've moved the template to another module and now it does compile... but don't ask me why it works ;-)